# Temporary paths for mobile site dev

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, path

I am creating a mobile version of a site to be converted to a simple app.

I have  folder 'mobile' which I will wrap up for the app, but, while I'm working on it, all the relative paths are screwed up - e.g. path

```
mobile
---->index1.html
----/js
----/css
----/dashHTML
    ---->index2.html
```

The site is all javascript, jquery & html so am having to add headers to each html page, no problem, for `index1.html` the following are fine:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

But of course for `index2.html` they are not fine as they are relative paths.

I know I could hardcode absolute paths but that would be a nightmare to manage each time I compile the app. Is there a solution where I can somehow 'fake' the folder `mobile` to be root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `base` tag in the `head`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

> The HTML `base` element specifies the base URL to use for all relative
>   URLs contained within a document.

Comment: A great answer thanks, will just have to remember to delete them!